# Load balancing in Hadoop

Tags: hadoop, load-balancing

How does load balancing in the hadoop environment. I have just started reading about the hadoop related stuffs. Would like to know how does the load balancing work in the entire ecosystem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hadoop  divides  the  input  to  a  MapReduce  job  into  fixed-size  pieces  called 
input
splits
, or just 
splits
. Hadoop creates one map task for each split, which runs the user-
defined map function for each 
record
 in the split.
Having many splits means the time taken to process each split is small compared to the
time to process the whole input. So if we are processing the splits in parallel, the pro-
cessing is better load-balanced if the splits are small, since a faster machine will be able
to process proportionally more splits over the course of the job than a slower machine.
Even if the machines are identical, failed processes or other jobs running concurrently
make load balancing desirable, and the quality of the load balancing increases as the
splits become more fine-grained.
On the other hand, if splits are too small, then the overhead of managing the splits and
of map task creation begins to dominate the total job execution time. For most jobs, a
good split size tends to be the size of an HDFS block, 64 MB by default, although this
can be changed for the cluster (for all newly created files), or specified when each file
is created.